# Using text field with AdapterView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-adapterview

Is it possible to use AdapterView with text fields in android?

My query returns a set of values and for each I want to place that within a textfield, so that the user may edit the value.

Also, I want to click a button to create a new empty field, so that I may insert a new entry.

If you know of good example, then please let me know!

**EDIT 1**

I would prefer to use XML to define ui and I found this informations:

"In this case we create a new id called text1. The + after the @ in the id string indicates that the id should be automatically created as a resource if it does not already exist, so we are defining text1 on the fly and then using it." Source http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

Will this + allow me to autocreate as many fields as needed?  Is there a way I can generically specify the layout in XML and then create fields adhoc based on db response?

Many thanks,

Mith

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use AdapterView with
>   text fields in android?

Yes. It will be complex for you (and possibly also for the user), so I would not recommend it unless you have a few months' Android programming experience, but it should work.

> Also, I want to click a button to
>   create a new empty field, so that I
>   may insert a new entry.

That will get a little complicated.

> Will this + allow me to autocreate as
>   many fields as needed?

No, that is not how you use `ListAdapters` for `ListView` rows.

> Is there a way I can generically
>   specify the layout in XML and then
>   create fields adhoc based on db
>   response?

Use a `CursorAdapter`.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that describes creating custom adapter classes. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) that shows creating a custom `CursorAdapter` to display the results of a database query.

Comment: What about the case where the data doesn't represent a list?